# What exactly does being a Muslim mean?

Tags: terminology, definitions, behavior

Can someone please give a brief answer describing the major and main responsibilities which is a must and sufficient enough to make a Muslim.

Please provide references as well.

Answer (score 5):

The Muslim is the person who has accepted Islam as his/her religion and prophet Muhammad (pbuh) as the Prophet of Islam. A real Muslim ought to say Shahadatain(2Shahadahs). As well as this, a Muslim ought to perform the orders of Islam.

There is a tradition from Prophet Muhammad (Pbuh) that said:

> The Muslim is a person that other Muslims must be comfortable from
>   his hands and tongue.

Imam Ali (a.s.) divided the Islam(Muslim) into six steps:

> Islam is submitting against the right and submitting is not possible
>   without Yaqin(certainty) and the certainty is validity and the
>   validity is confession (it means it is not sufficient that Islam and
>   faith(Iman) stays in heart and spirit of human, haply ought to express
>   it with dare and power)  and confession for doing the duty and doing
>   the duty is performing the orders of Allah.

On the other hand, according to Shia, there are five Osul al Din or 5 principles (Articles) of the religion or faith which a Muslim must believe in them and they consist of:

> 1: Tawhid (oneness)
>
> 2: Adalah (justice)
>
> 3: Nubuwwah (prophet-hood)
>
> 4: Imamah (leadership)
>
> 5: yawm al Qiyyamah ( the day of resurrection)

And likewise In accordance with Shia, the ten Ancillaries of the Faith (furūʿ ad-dīn) (فروع الدين} have practices that a Muslim must perform:

> 1 Salāt (Prayer)
>
> 2 Sawm (Fast)
>
> 3 Hajj (Pilgrimage)
>
> 4 Zakāh (Charity)
>
> 5 Khums (One-fifth)
>
> 6 Jihād (Struggle)
>
> 7 Amr-Bil-Ma'rūf (Commanding what is good)
>
> 8 Nahi-Anil-Munkar (Forbid what is evil)
>
> 9 Tawalla (Expressing love towards Good )
>
> 10 Tabarra (Expressing disassociation from Evil)
>
> ---

**Sources:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa3804)
- [www.porsojoo.com](http://www.porsojoo.com/fa/node/31176)

Comment: so interest to go jannat is not in the main list , if u do well u go to jannat , but its not mandatory to be interested in going jannat rather than doing good tasks

Comment: yeah, precisely you are right buddy. I agree with you.

Answer (score 4):

A person who **just** believes in

- oneness of Allah
- Muhammad (PBUH) is the last prophet of Allah and all other prophets sent before him
- the Day of judgment
- all Angels
- all Holy Books

Is called a *believer*. In Arabic and in Quran the word *[Momin](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momin)* is used for them which means/translates to *believer*.

On the other hand, a **Muslim** is a Momin/believer who observes and practically follows Islam, mainly following *[Pillars of Islam](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Pillars_of_Islam)*

- Declaring that there is no God but Allah
- Declaring that Muhammad (PBUH) is God's last Prophet
- *Salat*: daily five times prayer
- *Zakat*: giving 2.5% of one's savings to the needy
- Fasting in the month of Ramadan
- *Hajj*: pilgrimage to Kabba at least once

**EDIT**:

I am taking literal meanings of *momin* and *Muslim*.

Muslim is, say, of higher rank than Momin. Once a momin (faithful) starts following Islam practically, he is a Muslim (obedient).

Once a Muslim *stops* practicing Islam, he is a momin. He (that specific person who stops practicing Islam because of laziness) may be called a hypocrite (minor hypocrite).

There are [two types of hypocrites](http://www.qsep.com/modules.php?name=aqtawhid&file=article&sid=6).

1. Major Hypocrite ( *Aetiqadi munafiq*).
2. Minor Hypocrite ( *Amlee munafiq*).

Comment: The same thing which I wrote below, but there is technical inaccuracy in your answer.... "A momin may not always be a muslim and a muslim may not always be a momin" e.g. lazy momin and a hypocrite respectively... plz note that...

Comment: Can you back up your claim that that "Muslim" is a higher rank than "Momin"? Because al-Hujarat 14 seems to paint exactly the opposite picture.

Comment: Are you referring to this: (Sahih International ) The bedouins say, "We  believed." Say, "You have not [yet] believed; but say [instead], 'We have submitted,' for faith has not yet entered your hearts. And if you obey Allah and His Messenger, He will not deprive you from your deeds of anything. Indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful."

Comment: @goldPseudo Once, when we were studying Surat Al-Ahzab, we had a great debate on this issue for over a week nearly. Our sir, who is highly qualified in Islamic studies, confirmed and assured us that Muslim is he who obeys Allah instead of just believing, and thus is of higher rank ( Sorry, I can't find better word than 'rank').

Answer (score -1):

[SUNNI VIEW]

From this question "[What is difference between Islam and Iman?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13128/what-is-difference-between-islam-and-iman)"
we can extract your answer...

> He then asked the Prophet "What is Islam"?

The Prophet replied:

> "**Islam is to worship Allah and not do shirk, to establish prayers (salat), to pay charity (zakat), to fast (sawm) during the month of Ramadan, and hajj to the house.**" [Sahihayn & Sunan]

A person who does the above things is a 'Muslim'(Person who does or follow 'Islam' - Submit to Allah).

May the creator guide us all.